# Django Test: Altered field in the database

Tags: django, django-tests

I'm trying to run the test for my application, Its giving messsage like

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "status" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
```

Oh, Its because i have altered the `CharField` to `IntegerField` using SQL syntax (Although migration was created for this change)

```
ALTER TABLE accounts ALTER COLUMN status TYPE integer USING (status::integer);
```

So when running the `test` command, is failing while creating the test database.

Is there any way around to this ?

Update:
Right now i'm skipping the part of running migrations using third party app using http[s://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-test-without-migrations/](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-test-without-migrations/)

Now test tables are being created but failing for a cache table

```
File "/home/naveen/ENV/automaticfleet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 128, in handle
    created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "/home/naveen/ENV/automaticfleet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 229, in sync_apps
    sql, references = connection.creation.sql_create_model(model, no_style(), seen_models)
  File "/home/naveen/ENV/automaticfleet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 82, in sql_create_model
    db_params = f.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
  File "/home/naveen/ENV/automaticfleet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 548, in db_parameters
    type_string = self.db_type(connection)
  File "/home/naveen/ENV/automaticfleet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonfield/fields.py", line 73, in db_type
    db_type = cache.get(cache_key)
  File "/home/naveen/ENV/automaticfleet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/db.py", line 65, in get
    "WHERE cache_key = %%s" % table, [key])
  File "/home/naveen/ENV/automaticfleet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/naveen/ENV/automaticfleet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/naveen/ENV/automaticfleet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "accounts_cache" does not exist
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you have both run `makemigrations` AND `migrate`, right? Can you post the migration's file contents here? Can you confirm that `migrate` has indeed changed the db field? If you make a manual test as a user do you experience the same? Any more details to provide? It is a bit vague as it is.

Comment: @Wtower facepalm, even if TS has forgotten "migrate" DB, test command by default creates brand new database considering all migrations https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database ... anyway TS can use this (if v. 1.8) "You can prevent the test databases from being destroyed by adding the --keepdb" and inspect if migrations performed

Comment: @madzohan  using --nomigrations option (Django 1.7), It will not apply migrations, But now facing a error for a cache table, saying table does not exists.

Comment: hmm sounds like third party package ... found this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-test-without-migrations/ thanks =)

Comment: @madzohan don't get too excited buddy. Trying to establish if the same thing happens outside of tests or anything else as the above comment is in order.